# Drawing shapes based on dimensional values in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to draw shapes in excel based on the dimensions like length, width and height given. I have a pallet on which I want to put these boxes with variable dimensions and stack them on each other.

I want to see picture of how many boxes I can fit on a pallet of 48" * 42" and how many layers I can make for a pallet that needs to be 54" in height.

Comment: I was able to draw the shapes based on this, but now I want to arrange these shapes on the pallet to see how much space it will occupy.Sub x()

Dim r As Long, s As Shape

For r = 9 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Len(Cells(r, "E")) > 0 And Len(Cells(r, "F")) > 0 Then
        Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Cells(r, "D").Left, Cells(r, 2).Top, Cells(r, "E") * 6, Cells(r, "F") * 6)
        s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = Cells(r, "A")
    End If
Next r

End Sub

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that additional information.